# Create bootable ISO from Live USB

Tags: iso-image, liveusb

I have created a Ubuntu 11.04 Live USB with Unetbootin. I was wondering if it was possible to create a bootable iso from the usb stick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reconsider the overall question and do as Thiago M suggests.  A Live CD needs to be configured to boot and pass off the boot sequence in a manner that differs from USB thumb drives.  There is a similar question about migrating between different thumb drives on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14435/cloning-a-bootable-usb-stick-to-a-different-size-stick is currently being discussed.  That technical challenge is much simpler than moving to a CD and it is quite complex so I would punt.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the image from the Ubuntu website and burn it to a CD, it will be a bootable Live install.

Comment: I think the point may be to avoid re-downloading the .iso if it can be generated from the USB stick.

Comment: @alhirzel is right. I was trying to avoid the re-download. However, as @zedman9991 pointed, it is not that simple, so I ended up re-downloading.