# Create an .iso from USB drive

Tags: usb-storage, iso-image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft)

I have Win 7 on a USB stick, non-iso. How do I get an iso of that?

Comment: If your question is related to [this](http://superuser.com/questions/294065/create-bootable-iso-from-live-usb) one, follow the answer there.

Comment: I don't think so. I need it for a Mac BootCamp install.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Personally I would prefer to use [Imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/). It's very easy to use and free. I use it all of the time. Have a look at it!

> ImgBurn is a lightweight CD / DVD / HD DVD / Blu-ray burning application that everyone should have in their toolkit!

Comment: Do follow the instructions at: http://mindthebandgap.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/how-to-convert-bootable-usb-into-an-iso-file/

Comment: It doesn't detect USB drives as a disk.

Comment: steps how to use it https://aatayyab.wordpress.com/2016/05/09/convert-bootable-usb-to-an-iso-image/

Comment: Good luck finding an installer without malware in 2021. All are full of crap.

Comment: @Alpha2k https://download.imgburn.com/SetupImgBurn_2.5.8.0.exe. Or do you mean that the download from their own website has malware as well?

Comment: @BrtH even the official one has malware

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking  for something similar to:

- [Win Image](http://www.winimage.com/winimage.htm)
- [List of Softwares](http://create.software.informer.com/download-create-bootable-iso-from-usb-key/)

About Win Image:

> WinImage is a fully-fledged disk-imaging suite for easy creation,
>   reading and editing of many image formats and fileystems, including
>   DMF, VHD, FAT, ISO, NTFS and Linux. The disk image is an exact copy of
>   a physical disk (floppy, CD-ROM, hard disk, USB, VHD disk, etc.) or a
>   partition that preserves the original structure. With WinImage in
>   place, you can recreate the disk image on the hard drive or other
>   media, view its content, extract image-based files, add new files and
>   directories, change the format, and defragment the image. All this and
>   more is delivered in one intuitive user interface that enables imaging
>   right out of the box.

WinImage has many cool features!

```
Create a disk image from a removable drive (like USB drive), CD-ROM, floppy,
Extract file(s) from a disk image,
Create empty disk images,
Inject files and directories into an existing disk image,
Change a disk image format,
Defragment a disk image,
A powerful "Batch assistant" mode that lets you automate many operations,
And many more!
```

How ever it is shareware available for trial for 30 days!

Comment: Thanks, but is there anything built-in into Windows or Mac?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: Well for Windows there is no software there by default, and it is easy to use these softwares so i suggested them. Accept if it helped and worked thanks