# Adding multiple iso's to a pen-drive

Tags: windows, boot, usb, multi-boot, iso-image

This may sound strange but I have all windows instillation iso's back to windows 95. Is there a way to add them all to a 512GB pen-drive and make it boot-able. So when I put the USB in it will give a dos like menu to choose the iso I want to boot from. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I place a bootable ISO on a USB drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/66948/how-do-i-place-a-bootable-iso-on-a-usb-drive) OR http://superuser.com/questions/294065/create-bootable-iso-from-live-usb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

I find it real usefull

Answer (score 1):

I use a Zalman external enclosure that supports CD Drive virtualization.  This is a superior solution than the yumi-multiboot-usb-creator because the ISO files don't need to be mangled in any way.

Just drop the ISO into the *ISO* folder on the Zalman and when you plug it in you can select the ISO from a list, no configuration or installing required.

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817379026